# Завершения приложения после закрытия основного окна в случае наследования классов

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Как завершить приложение закрыв основное окно при открытом втором?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
import sys

# Родительский класс главного окна
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(551, 258)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn_settings = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    # Здесь различные компоненты размещены

# Родительский класс второго окна
class Ui_Settings_form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Settings_form):
        Settings_form.setObjectName("Settings_form")
        Settings_form.resize(262, 300)
    # Здесь различные компоненты размещены

# Дочерний класс второго окна
class Settings(Ui_Settings_form):       
    def setupUi2(self, MainWindow, parent):
        super().setupUi(MainWindow)
        self.parent = parent

        self.list = 0

# Дочерний класс первого окна
class Terminal(Ui_MainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        super().setupUi(MainWindow)
        self.add_function()
    
    def add_function(self):
        self.btn_settings.clicked.connect(self.form_settings_open)
  
    def form_settings_open(self):
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Settings()
        ui.setupUi2(self.widget, self)
        # Правильно ли таким образом передавать данные из одной формы в другую?
        ui.list = ['one', 'two']
        self.widget.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Информация',
            "Вы хотите закрыть все окна?",
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.form.close()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Terminal()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PS: такая иерархия классов правильная или лучше по другому делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета,
и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton


# форма второго окна
class Ui_Settings_form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Settings_form):
        Settings_form.setObjectName("Settings_form")
        Settings_form.resize(262, 300)
    # Здесь различные компоненты размещены
    

# форма главного окна
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(551, 258)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btn_settings = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    # Здесь различные компоненты размещены
            

# Второе окно
class Settings(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Settings_form):                         # +++  Ui_Settings_form      
    def __init__(self): #, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                                                   # +++
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.move(50, 50)
        self._list = 0 
      
            
# Главное окно
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                      # +++ Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                                                   # +++
        self.add_function()
        
        self.widget = Settings()                                             # !!!
    
    def add_function(self):
        self.btn_settings.clicked.connect(self.form_settings_open)
  
    def form_settings_open(self):
        self.widget._list = ['one', 'two']                                   # ! _list
        self.widget.label.setText('\n'.join(self.widget._list))
        self.widget.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Информация',
            "Вы хотите закрыть все окна?",
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
             QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.widget.close()                                               # ! widget
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @helldrg спросите, если что-то не понятно

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь все понятно стало мне

Comment: уточню на всякий случай, уже спрашивал у Вас, если захочу после манипуляций во второй форме передать значение какое нибудь или массив в первую форму, то нужно передавать в форму Settings указатель на главную форму, назвать указатель parent и передавать значение например так: self.parent.text = result Правильно?

Comment: @helldrg пожалуйста. Давайте так поступим, если вы что-то захотите сделать, то сразу попробуете сделать самостоятельно. Если что-то не будет получаться - зададите новый вопрос и я попробую вам помочь.

Comment: Хорошо, просто интересно как люди с опытом реализовали бы те или иные моменты. Спасибо